# Is it possible to draw figures like these?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

Is it possible to draw figures like these or is better to just paste it?

[image]
[image]

If it is, what are the best tools or good examples to do it?

Example: `\draw`, `\node`.

Using Ti*k*Z is being my work until now:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}           
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,fit,shapes.gates.logic.US, shapes.gates.logic.IEC, calc}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) .. controls (3,-1.8) and (0.5,-3.2) .. (0.75,-5);
    \draw (0.12,0.06) .. controls (3.12,-1.8) and (0.62,-3.2) .. (0.87,-5);
    \draw[dashed] (1.116,-0.2) -- (1.991,-2.8);
    \draw[thick, ->] (1.65,-1.4188) -- (1.4025,-0.6875);
    \coordinate (P) at (3.6,-2);
    \draw[->] (1.65,-1.4188) -- (P);
    \draw[thick, ->] (1.65,-1.4188) -- (2.3813, -1.6368);
    \draw[line width = 1.15mm] (1.44,-1.35) -- (1.51, -1.56);
    \path (3.8,-2.08) node(x) [circle,draw,scale=0.4] {$\times$};
    \coordinate [label=below left:$ds$] (ds) at (1.4,-1.3);
    \coordinate [label=above right:$ids$] (ids) at (1.41,-0.7);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$\hat{r}$] (hr) at (1.74,-1.53);
    \coordinate [label=above right:$r$] (r) at (2.9,-1.85);
    \coordinate (ci) at (0.45, -4.7);
    \coordinate (ce) at (0.6, -3.9);
    \draw[->] (ci) to [bend left] node [left] {$i$} (ce);


    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But depending on time constraints and how much of a graphics package you already know, you may want to just use `\includegraphics`. My recommendation is TikZ, but of course others prefer `pstricks`, `picture` mode, Asymptote, MetaPost, `\pdfliteral` primitive commands, etc., etc. :-)

Comment: From your previous questions, it seems that you already use TikZ for diagrams. If you want to draw these, have you tried? What, in particular, is causing you trouble?

Comment: Pstricks can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips PaulGessler, Bernard I'm going to read more about these graphic packages. cfr, tikz and circuitkz was everything I was using until now, I made the question to know if there are better tools for it because I know that this will be very time spending. I already did some work in tikz.

Comment: Vector graphics will look better than raster graphics, especially zoomed-in, but if you can include a vector graphic, that’s effectively equivalent.